# Changing the name of the table of contents

Tags: table-of-contents, babel, dutch

So I want to change the name of the toc from "Contents" to "Inhoudsopgave"
I have already tried using a babel package and

```
\renewcommand{\contentsname}{Inhoudsopgave}
```

But neither have worked so far. Are there any other options?

Comment: Please add a [short, but compilable test file](//tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) which allows us to reproduce the problem. It should include a class, the necessary packages and a `document` environment.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE.

Comment: \addto\captionsdutch{\renewcommand\contentname{Foobar}}

Comment: @daleif - The OP hasn't confirmed yet that `babel` is getting loaded with the `dutch` language option.

Answer (score 0):

When asking a question on TeX.SE about just about any problem, it's invariably an excellent idea to post a [minimally compilable example](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-working-example-mwe-what-is-that) or test document that replicates the issue that needs fixing.

For sure, though, the following minimally compilable document

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[dutch]{babel}
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\end{document}
```

generates a section-level title that, you guessed it, says "Inhoudsopgave".

If *your* document does not generate this output, it must be because there's some (as of now) undisclosed setting in your document that's messing things up.